# Designing split-phase grid-tie solar system

Tags: transformer, inverter, solar-energy, split-phase

I'm in the process of designing and building a grid-tied solar power system, and had I'm having trouble finding a solar inverter that isn't MASSIVE (the smallest one I can find that meets my use cases and outputs split phase power is 6kw). The entire system will likely never go over 2kw~ of panels and 1.5-2kw inverter. I don't really want to just feed one side of the house -- I have whole-home power monitoring in place and because of the way this old place is wired, one of the split phases is typically 1kw+ more loaded than the other. I don't want to contribute to this or create a situation where if it's later corrected, my solar system now creates a large imbalance.

So I was wondering if it would be possible to use a large 1:1 isolation transformer with a centertap on one side -- feed 240v single phase into the transformer from a 240v inverter, then the center-tapped side to the L1, L2, and N for the house. Would something like this work? Is there a better way? Is if safe? I've seen a few 'autotransformers' around supposedly designed for this purpose, but I've had trouble confirming they can be used this way outside of marketing.

My questions are basically:

1). Can I use a big bare 1:1 wound transformer center tapped on one side to input 240 single phase and grid-tie to 240 split-phase on the other side? (Or even a 120v -> 240v centertapped with a single 120v inverter)

2). Would an actual 'autotransformer' like the ones made by Victron or Outback be better? Is it worth the $400~ more for the metal case they come in over buying a bare xfmr and wiring it myself?

3). Is there a better/safer way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or should I not care at all and just feed one of the split phases with a 120v grid-tie inverter?

Comment: I don't have a comprehensive view here. Just an opinion, assuming it's grid-tied. I suspect that the reason the smallest inverter is about 6 kW is because (1) it's a lot of trouble, circuitry-wise; and, (2) anyone needing to go to all that trouble (and pay for it, plus get power company permissions) is probably going to be dealing with more capacity in order to properly balance the costs. Or, in short, the marketplace for 2 kW inverters is too small to make it worth anyone's trouble providing the units. I think you are in a "small marketplace" that isn't well-served. Welcome to the club.

Comment: And no, not a single one of your suggestions comes anywhere close to something that can be grid-tied. So far as my own limited perspective allows, anyway. Just FYI.

Comment: No, to all your proposals.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is using a transformer will most likely mess up with the synchronization of the inverter with the grid. But sorry, I can't yet propose a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone -- I have to admit I'm a little confused, as everyone seems to be in agreement none of these options will work, yet these devices: 

https://www.victronenergy.com/autotransformers/autotransformers

https://www.altestore.com/store/enclosures-electrical-safety/miscellaneous-electrical-parts/transformers/outback-psx-240-autotransformer-with-fan-p4089/

seem to be kind of purpose made for something like this? I'm extremely confused. :(